# Powershell, Invoke-WebRequest where/ how to include my token (for spotify api)?

Tags: powershell, spotify

So this is what Ive got so far. In order to use [the api](https://developer.spotify.com/) I need to provide my token, but there seems to be no parameter that wouldlet me do so.  Thanks in advance! <3

Edit: [Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest#-headers) wont work (cant enter strings).

```
 $accept = 'application/json'
 $authorization = 'BQDwgz....g1-KGRR'
 $link = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/spotifycharts/playlists/<id>/tracks'


    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $link -ContentType $accept -??? $authorization -Method Get
```

Comment: `-Headers` is your friend. See #6 in https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/.

Comment: Headers was what I used at first but [headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest#-headers) doesn't allow me to enter a string. :/

Comment: the header value expected by invoke-webrequest is an array. You would instantiate it like this: `$headers = @{ Authorization = $basicAuthValue }`
and then use it: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $link -headers $headers`
I don't know what headers you need but I think @TomDavies has you covered with the link above.

Comment: Thank you Ty &  @Tom Davies. <3